# cronjob not running with codeigniter

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I am sure the answer is right in front of me, but this is driving me crazy.  I have searched high and low for the answer and can't find it.  Essentially I am trying to run a script through a `cronjob` on my server and nothing is working.  However, when I run it with the PHP command line, it works fine.

The desired effect is to send an email periodically.  So, when I run this:

```
php /var/www/html/index.php email_controller index
```

The email sends and everything works fine.  I am calling the `email_controller` controller and the `index` method.  The `index` method isn't necessary and works if I leave it off as well.

My `crontab` looks like this:

```
18 15 * * * php /var/www/html/index.php email_controller index
```

To run the script at 3:18 PM.  This does not work.  `cron` is running, I've checked.

Any ideas here?

Comment: i have never used minutes with a leading 0, just a thought

Comment: @Dagon, actually, that was the wrong line.  I edited my question and posted the right one.

Comment: so it runs from the command line but not as a cronjob? if hosted, ask the host, try the full path to php, set an email address in the crontab file -which will send you errors. my 'guesses'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3:18PM is 15:18 Also, don't forget set full path to php interpreter:

```
18 15 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/index.php email_controller index
```

Comment: -f option tells php that next token is script file

Comment: This worked.  Havenard had the same answer you did, but you had the answer in first.  Problem was PHP path wasn't right.  Setting the path fixed it.  Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the full path to the binary, its probably `/usr/bin/php` but use `whereis php` to get the correct path.

Besides that I don't see why this shouldn't be working. Does it work if ran manually?

Are you using `crontab -e` to add the task? Make some tests with a debug script, make it run every minute with `* * * * *` so you can debug it:

```
// debugcrontab.php
<?php

    file_put_contents('Ran at ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n", '/tmp/debug.txt', FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

In case it still fail try `/bin/sh /usr/bin/php ...`

I use this one in my server and it works just fine:

```
0 3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/update_reports.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Worked, problem was not specifying the PHP path completely.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after using correct PHP path it worked for me.

Use:

/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php controllername methodname

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the path to your PHP executable is correct; for me it was `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Try `which php` to get the path for your default php - or try `/usr/bin/env php`.